# Ionic 3 Native Google Maps + Google Places + Geolocation

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I've spent too much time making this work, but failed to do so.
I am using Native Google Maps and I would like to do a simple Google Places Nearby Search, to populate markers on the map.

I have managed to make it work without Native Google Maps. However, the markers would populate only in a browser and not on the native device. That is the reason why I started using native Google Maps. However, I could not make nearbySearch work on a native google map. Here is my code.

native-maps.js

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMaps, LatLng, GoogleMapsEvent } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var google: any;

@Injectable()
export class NativeMapsProvider {

  map: any;

  constructor(public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {}

  init(location, element) {

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create(element.nativeElement, opts);

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');
      let googleFormatLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);  // ?
      service.nearbySearch({
        location: googleFormatLocation,
        radius: 10000,
        type: ['restaurants']
      }, (results,status) => {
        console.log("STATUS: ", status);
        console.log("RESULTS: ", 20);
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,     // or something else?
      position: placeLoc,
      title: "Marker",
    });    
  }
}
```

I believe that the initialisation of the variable service is the key, since I have had different problems while tweaking the PlacesService constructor, while passing different objects:

- google.maps.Map(element.nativeElement) -> This works and the console prints STATUS: OK, RESULTS: 20. However, the map disappears and 'Map is ready' is not printed to the console.
- this.map or this.googleMaps -> Places do not work, no STATUS or RESULT logged in the console

find-places.ts

```
// Function ionViewDidLoad()
let options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 25000
};


this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {

  this.location = {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  };

  this.mapsProvider.init(this.location, this.mapElement);

 }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
 });
```

Please note that I use ionic cordova build ios --prod and test the application from XCode.

Javascript, iOS and Android keys are created in the Google Console and not even restricted yet.

index.html constains the following:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places";
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SAME_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```